# Don't update modified post date when user add a product review or comment?

Tags: php, posts, woocommerce-offtopic, date

I am using WooCommerce and I added the following code on `content-single-product.php`template to show last update of product:

```
<p class="data-label">Updated</p>
<p class="info"> <?php echo get_the_modified_time( 'F j, Y' ); ?> </p>
```

On single product pages I have enable reviews tab and comment tab so customer can add comment on a product.

The problem is when user add new review or comment to product, the last update date for the

product is changed to the date of its comment.

I don't want to change the last update date of product when user add new comment on any product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooCommerce seems to update the 'last modified' value of a product on every change. If you want to take a look at the source code, go to `woocommerce\includes\data-stores\class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php` and check the function `update`.

This solution seems to work, however it could be improved to make sure it doesn't mess up with anything else. Basically checks if the request has info of a comment and filters the query that modifies the post date to skip it. I didn't find any earlier hook than the `query` filter.

```
add_filter('query', function($query){
    if(isset($_POST['comment']) && strpos($query, 'post_modified')){
        return '';
    }
    return $query;
});
```